# Build DLL when source is outside of sln

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have the following folder setup in my visual studio project:

[image]

When I open the sln in visual studio, it contains everything in the www folder.

My problem is that there is source code inside the _source folder, and i have made changes to this source code, and want to build the DLL. As it is not in my VS project, I cannot build this DLL.

Usually, i would expect the sln to be one level higher and it would then include the _source folder.

However, this is not the case. I have tried rearranging the folder, but this does not work.

I do not think the solutionis to put the _source folder in the www folder, I am not sure if that would work, and I feel this may be a bit hacky? If it did work, how would I tell it to make a DLL and where to biuld to?

I have tried adding an existing item, but that will only let me add an individual file, not a folder, which makes me suspect that is not the solution either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the source folder into a solution project so to include it in the build, a solution is a collection of projects, your code must be included in a project for it to build, add your source to the project you want it to build with.

Move your source folder into the folder containing the project file (.csproj/.vbproj) and within visual studio select the project click onthe show all files icon, right click on your folder and 'include in project'.